# Googledrive DFP python client horrendously slow

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-dfp

I'm querying the DFP API using the python client. I'm trying to get the last 2 years of creatives but the client is unusably slow. I mean, it's taken about 20 minutes to download 352,256 bytes (compressed).

Specifically I'm using the following filter:

```
// last_modified = today - 2 years
statement = dfp.FilterStatement("WHERE '%sT00:00:00' < "
                                "lastModifiedDateTime" % last_modified)
```

Why is it so slow and how can I speed it up? I'm seeing literally 4-5 minutes between writes to my output file using the following loop:

```
while True:
    response = subservice(statement.ToStatement())

    if 'results' in response:
        for result in response['results']:
            formatted_result = formatter(result)

            if formatted_result:
                output_file.write(json.dumps(formatted_result) + "\n")

        statement.offset += dfp.SUGGESTED_PAGE_LIMIT
    else:
        break
```